# Unit Testing for the web?

Tags: unit-testing

I have been doing a lot a reading about unit testing.

Unit testing seems all well and good.
But it seems to miss a lot of the fundamentals of how the web works. User Interaction.

I have not seen any way a unit test could test for unexpected input, or test to make sure that an ajax call works etc.

Am I missing something here or is unit testing not really designed well for web development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything.

Ideally unit testing is about testing a small piece of code, e.g. a class in isolation. For this you may want to use a unit testing tools such as JUnit or NUnit. Some people refer to this type of tests as developer tests.

In contrast to that you may want to test web applications as a whole. Some call this acceptance testing. For the latter you could use a tool such as Selenium. Tools like Selenium can test Ajax and other JavaScript as well.

You have even more options if you take a look at a tool like [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) as you will find that you can implement Selenium-based tests using a unit testing tool.

Comment: Out of curiosity. When unit testing server side code, how would you simulate a mysql result object?

or would you actually run the query to generate that result object?

Comment: I'm using (N)Hibernate so the result object is transparent to me. For testing I can reconfigure to use an in-memory database such as SQLite to speed up test execution. In most cases it is now fast enough that I don't need to simulate/mock the result from a criteria query. In that sense I'm actually running the query. I'm just using a very fast database (in-memory) if you like.

Comment: I see,
How do you handle tests which actually do something to the database (eg delete a user from the database).

If that is not your actual test, simply part of an expected process would you simply exclude the query and put true (i.e just tell your test that that part succeeded) or would you actually run the query anyway?

Comment: I would run the query or the tests anyways as the behavior is in principal the same, e.g. deleting a user. The only difference is that the database server is not running on a remote host. Instead the "server" is running locally in-memory. That way you cut out cross-process calls, file access and the network. That's what makes it significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.